# smartfield annotation - valuehelp dropdown

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a value help field and want to see only descriptions (not codes) in the dropdown. After selection, want to store the code in another field which would be in hidden mode. For this, I have defined the following annotation:

```xml
<Annotations Target="Metadata.CallReport/DivisionText">
  <Annotation Term="Common.ValueList">
    <Record Type="Common.ValueListType">
      <PropertyValue Property="CollectionPath" String="CustomizingDivisionSet" />
      <PropertyValue Property="Parameters">
        <Collection>
          <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterOut">
            <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" PropertyPath="DivisionText" />
            <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="Text" />
          </Record>
          <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterOut">
            <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" PropertyPath="Division" />
            <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="Value" />
          </Record>
        </Collection>
      </PropertyValue>
      <PropertyValue Property="SearchSupported" Bool="false" />
    </Record>
  </Annotation>
</Annotations>
```

And the view definition..

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<smartField:SmartField textLabel="Division" value="{DivisionText}">
  <smartField:configuration>
    <smartField:Configuration controlType="dropDownList" displayBehaviour="descriptionOnly" />
  </smartField:configuration>
</smartField:SmartField>
<!-- ... -->
```

Everything works fine; the code for the description I have selected is copied to `Division` field. However, when I change this dropdown field, the selection works, but the code does not get copied to `Division` field.

Comment: Any news on this topic? I'm experiencing the same issue and I can't find  much info about it

Comment: you must generate a link between the Description and the Key you want to display in the same _EntitySet_ you contain both.

For instance, if you link EntityA to EntityB where EntityB is providing us the ID and the Description, you need to link in EntityB ID saying that the Text is taken from Description. In you case will be something like:

`<Annotations Target="Metadata.CallReport/Text xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
    <Annotation Term="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1.Text" Path="Value"/>
   </Annotations>`